# npm install faills with python module errors

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install and run a react project which I bought from the internet. wheever, I run npm install I get the following error

```
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /home/AzureUser/Python3/python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /home/AzureUser/Python3/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/tmp/thermo-api/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/tmp/thermo-api/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.21.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I am very new to node.js and I am not sure what is wrong?

Comment: Node-gyp only works with `python2.7`, you have to install it first and install `python-dev`

Comment: yes, I have to install python 2.7 as well in addition to 3.7. How to make gyp work with my python 2.7 version?

Comment: try to install node-gyp globally in your machine: <sudo> npm install -g node-gyp and try to make a build in your project again.

Comment: what's the erro messages?